# How to execute a privileged action from a CGI script

Tags: bash, apache, service, cgi, init.d

I want to restart a linux service from a shell CGI script, which obviously requires root rights. I'm kind of out of options that I know of:

- Giving root access to my web server seems very dangerous
- Using `setuid` on my CGI script [doesn't work and people say it's generally a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)
- Writing another service and communicating with it from my CGI through some kind of IPC - seems like a huge overkill

What are the best practices of doing something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a [sudoer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621128/3886428) . As a best practice always provide the apache user as little rights as it needs.

Edit the sudoers file with `sudo visudo` and add a line

```
apache        ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service /usr/local/myapp *
```

Comment: What is `myapp`? Is this the path to the CGI script?

Comment: It should be the specific command you want to provide access to. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246430